# NOT NULL constraint failed while copying data to a new table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I migrate my database from SQLiteOpenHelper to Room.

I have a table that I want to change, lets call it `"my_table"`.
Its simplified create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table`
 (`_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `title` TEXT
 )
```

During an upgrade among other changes I add the new column `type INTEGER NOT NULL` (I'm adding Foreign Key aswell and doing other significant changes, that's the reason to create a new table instead of altering the existing one):

```
CREATE TABLE "new_table" 
 (`_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `title` TEXT,
  `type` INTEGER NOT NULL
 )
```

Then I want to copy data from the `my_table` to the `new_table` and set `type` column's values.

*SQL statement:*

```
INSERT INTO new_table (title) 
SELECT title FROM my_table;
UPDATE new_table SET type = 1;
DROP TABLE my_table;
ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO my_table;
```

*Android migration:*

```
public static final Migration MIGRATION_TEST = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Create new table
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE new_table (`_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `title` TEXT, `type` INTEGER NOT NULL)");
        // Copy some data
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO new_table (title) SELECT title FROM old_table"); // constraint violation
        // Insert default value into the measures column
        database.execSQL("UPDATE new_table SET type = 1");
        // Delete old table
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE old_table");
        // Rename new table
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO my_table");
    }
};
```

Obviously I get `NOT NULL constraint failed: new_table.type` error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: new_table.type (code 1299)
Error Code : 1299 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)
Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
(NOT NULL constraint failed: new_table.type (code 1299))
```

I can avoid it by changing new table's create statement and setting default value for the `type` column.

```
CREATE TABLE "new_table" 
 (`_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `title` TEXT,
  `type` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
 )
```

But I don't want to do this as Room doesn't suport default values out of the box and in order to avoid future mistakes when inserting new values into tables.

Are there any workarounds to avoid this error while inserting data to a new table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following may work :-

```
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO new_table (title,type) SELECT title, 1 FROM old_table");
```

That is, you are now saying to INSERT 2 columns as per the SELECT statement. The SELECT returns 2 values the title from the old_table and the literal value 1.

- That is SELECT actual returns the result of expressions [result-column](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/result-column.html) which aren't limited to just columns. An Expression can be literal value, result of functions, results of operations and other [expr](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/expr.html)
- As per

  - > The list of expressions between the SELECT and FROM keywords is known
    >   as the result expression list.
- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - SELECT - 3. Generation of the set of result rows.](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

You then wouldn't need `database.execSQL("UPDATE new_table SET type = 1")`.

Comment: That works! Thank you. I haven't seen this in examples of the `INSERT` statement (or maybe didn't notice). Can you provide a link to where this behavior explained, please?

Comment: Basically SELECT ...... is a list of expressions *The number of columns in the rows returned by a simple SELECT statement is equal to the number of expressions in the result expression list after substitution of and alias. expressions. Each result row is calculated by evaluating the expressions in the result expression list with respect to a single row of input data or, for aggregate queries, with respect to a group of rows.* [expr](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/expr.html) as **literal value**

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike, for the answer and the explanation!